# Has the Youtube thumbnail URL changed?

Tags: youtube-api

I got a specific thumbnail URL using the Youtube Data API, but I've found, that the URL's changed and is different from another video thumbnail URLs:

```
https://i9.ytimg.com/vi/PBczmHyvtOo/default.jpg?sqp=CPSJ2b8F&rs=AOn4CLBKDvsNAcfu8l16O4rl3TnLpLSDuw
```

What do the GET-parameters stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video that you are attempting to get the thumbnail of is private.  In order to give only authorized entities access to the thumbnail and keep the thumbnail private from others additional parameters are needed to make sure only authorized entities can access this video thumbnail.

Please note that you may have inadvertently exposed this private thumbnail to the world by posting the full URL.